# increment while holding button down-material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a button that I want to use to increment a value. I have figured out with on Click how to make it increment. I would like though to have the ability for it to keep incrementing while I hold the button down. How do you accomplish this with material ui?

Comment: It doesn't matter what react ui framework we work with to get your request working. It is pure React work.

Comment: I asked for a solution using material ui, and believe it will already be built in to material ui, but cant find it in the documentation. I dont understand at all why I should not try use a framework for this, even if I can solve it normally as you said below. There is so much code below, for what is probably just a prop that I can't figure out. #don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      zoom: 1,
    }
    this.t = undefined
    this.between = 400   //time bewtween timer
    this.repeat = this.repeat.bind(this)
    this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this)
    this.onMouseUp = this.onMouseUp.bind(this)
    this.increase = this.increase.bind(this)
  }
  increase(){
    this.setState({zoom: this.state.zoom +1})
  }
  repeat() {
    this.increase();
    this.t = setTimeout(this.repeat, this.between)
   }

  onMouseDown() {
    this.repeat();
  }
  onMouseUp() {
    clearTimeout(this.t)
    this.between = 400
  }
 
 render() {
   return <div>
     <div> {this.state.zoom}</div>
     <button onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp} onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}>+</button>
     </div>
    }
 }
export default App;
```

Comment: I asked for a solution using material ui, and believe it will already be built in to material ui, but cant find it in the documentation. I dont understand at all why I should not try use a framework for this, even if I can solve it normally as you said above. There is so much code above, for what is probably just a prop that I can't figure out. #don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

found a library called repeatable: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-repeatable.
I just enclosed my button with

```
<Repeatable onHold={...}> <button>...</button> </Repeatable>
```